# Sound entirely stopped working on Windows 8 on a Macbook Pro

Tags: audio, macbook-pro, windows-8, windows-services

I am currently running Windows 8 (downloaded from DreamSpark) on a Macbook Pro. This worked fine for a while but suddenly all audio stopped working. When I go to "Playback devices" and hit "Test" on the speakers I get treated with the following message:

[image: screenshot of error message]

This also shows up right after I try restarting. I tried disallowing exclusive usage of the devices but it makes no difference.

Edit:
After some looking around I tried changing the sample rate and bit depth so I would get a dialog screen to force Windows to go around the program that's using it. I did get the dialog but then instead of changing it I got the following error:

[image: screenshot of error message]

Edit 2:
I narrowed it down to a single service failing to start, the Multimedia Class Scheduler service fails to start with the following error:

[image: screenshot of error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while suddenly a red light wend on in the headphone jack, I simply plugged in a non-optical headset and it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

Try the solutions posted by thecraigmcrae and Robin Fleming [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowspro-audiodevelopment/thread/b09e43ba-3ffa-4a45-9593-8eee686f124a/) or phyllismc's solution [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/itprovistahardware/thread/79379e67-d032-463b-a1de-e7834bbc050a). Don't know if it's the same problem, but sounds similar.

Specifically, Robin's:

> Right click "Computer"
>   Click "Manage"
>   Under the "System Tools" section, Double click "Local Users and Groups"
>   Click "Groups"
>   Right click "Administrators"
>   Click "Add to group..."
>   Click "Add"
>   Click "Advanced"
>   Click "Find Now"
>   Double click "Local Service"
>   Click "Ok"
>   "NT Authority\Local Service" should show up in the list now
>   Click "Ok"
>   Close Computer Management and reboot.

Phyllis's:

> On your Start Menu, in the StartSearch Box, type:  `services.msc`
>   When the Services Window pops up, find: Windows Audio and Windows Audio Endpoint
>   Right click on these two services and Restart.

and

> Windows Start menu, choose 'Run...'. In the pop-up box, type: `regedit`.
>   Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Ole`
>   Delete the registry key `DefaultAccessPermission`. (If it isn't there,
>   chances are this isn't the problem causing your lack of sound.)

and Craig's:

> 1 Go to control panel
>   2. Double-Click on the Sound Icon
>   3. Single-click the Speakers to highlight them
>   4. Click on Properties (bottom right corner)
>   5. Go to the Enhancements Tab and Click on it
>   6. Now click "Disable All Sound Effects"
>   7. Click OK and you should be good to go!

Comment: First one didn't fix it. Second one doesn't apply since I restarted anyways. Third one, there is no key named that. And the last one didn't fix it either.

Answer (score 0):

I know a lot of mac users having the same problem i dont know how to fix it but if your unable to get sound working try reinstalling the mac osx and get this software called parallel windows found [here](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) this will let you run osx and windows without any problems

Comment: Re-installing OSX will do nothing because the problem is in windows and not in OSX and it appears to be a problem with one of the services. Also I have no need for parallels because I just dual boot windows with rEFIt.

Comment: did you have sound to start with or have you never had sound when booting windows?